# Log screen session to a file other then screenlog.0

Tags: gnu-screen

I have multipal screen sessions that are started like this...

```
/usr/bin/screen -A -m -d -S tower /usr/local/bin/vmpsd -a 10.0.1.214 -d -f /usr/local/vmpsdb/tower.db
```

I would like to log this screen session to /var/log/tower.log

Any ideas on how I can do this.. I have tried using tee, but that did not work.

Comment: I imagine you can redirect the output to /var/log/tower.log (provided you have permissions). Does that work? just append a "> /var/log/tower.log" at the end of your command and see it if works

Comment: I can't even redirect the output.  If I do a > at the end.. I get nothing in the output file.. I have tried using tee to no avil...

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
screen -dmS <sock_name>                         #Start detached screen session<br>
screen -S <sock_name> -X logfile <logfile_name> #Use logfile command to set logging file<br>
screen -S <sock_name> -X log                    #Use log command to start logging<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `script` command inside `screen` session.

Comment: Could you explain further?